# Navbar links extend offscreen

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to code a Navbar using HTML and CSS. When resizing the window, the links extend off the right side of the viewport. They are not moving left, but staying in their current position.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navbar .container {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar__logo {
  color: rgb(34, 204, 57);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.navbar__logo span {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar__link:hover {
  color: rgb(34, 204, 57);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__link .active a {
  color: rgb(34, 204, 57) !important;
}


/* Utilities */

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 1220px;
  width: 1220px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" / -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar__logo">Some<span>Website</span></div>
        <div class="navbar__links">
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link active">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide code in your question. By posting that URL as code you bypassed this requirement. Also take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

You're hard coding widths which makes your links shunt off the right hand edge of the screen. Change .navbar to

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;

  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

and .container to

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

and it should work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navbar .container {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar__logo {
  color: rgb(34, 204, 57);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.navbar__logo span {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar__link:hover {
  color: rgb(34, 204, 57);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__link .active a {
  color: rgb(34, 204, 57) !important;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" / -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar__logo">Some<span>Website</span></div>
        <div class="navbar__links">
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link active">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: THANKS! It's working, can I just add the min-width back to the container or should I use left & right?

Comment: If you use left and right properties the nav bar will always be the full width of the screen.  min-width will stop the nav bar shrinking any further when the browser window is resized and you'll get a scroll bar which is probably not what you want. If you want to make it mobile-friendly then have a look at media queries and responsive layout.  A good primer can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

dont use fix properties (px) use (view-width, vw). 100vw means the all the width of the screen. because when you use px it will work just on your screen but on smaller or bigger screens it will break.

**vw is relative to the width of the viewport**

`.navbar { width: 100vw;}` https://codepen.io/wtechoud/pen/BaxaByz?editors=1100

if you still doesn't know what vw mean this is a good tutorial to watch:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GR52czEd-0

Comment: Hey, I've tried doing so. The bug still isn't fixed, But thanks for telling me that!